# configure prometheus targets to read metrics from text file

Tags: prometheus

is it possible to configure Prometheus to use text file as the source of metrics?

i tried config prometheus.yml like below but that not works.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'custom_job'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['C:\CustomJobLogs\metrics.txt']
```

does Prometheus support metrics from text file or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use windows, use textfile collector from [wmi_exporter](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter)

and if you use linux, use textfile collector from [node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this seems not possible:

```
  static_configs:

     -targets: ['C:\CustomJobLogs\metrics.txt']
```

But, it can be dobe by exposing metrics.txt to http and add the targets to that host:port

*prometheus.yaml* can be configured:

```
global:
    scrape_interval: 10s
scrape_configs:
    - job_name: example
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
    - targets:
        - localhost:5000
```

Example for exposing the metrics.txt to http using flask(wsgi or any other can also be used):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/metrics", methods=['GET'])
def getfile():
    with open("metrics.txt", "r+") as f:
        data = f.read()
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost')
```